# timer stop & continue function in only one button in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to build a timer controlled by one start button. when clicked, it will change innertext to "stop" and start the countdown, when clicked again, it will change to "continue" and pause the countdown. The problem is I don't know how to control the setinterval, because I declare it in dfferent if statment, I can't access the setinterval variable from other place.
Code:

```
const change = document.getElementById("change") -> countdown text part
const sb = document.getElementById("start") // button -> stop & pause
let stop = true; 
let i; // setinterval variable


sb.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let a = parseInt(change.innerText);
    if(stop && a != 0) {
        stop = false;
        sb.innerText = "Stop";
        i = setInterval(()=> {
        a --;
        change.innerText = a;
        if(a == 0) {
            stop = true;
            alert("Time's Out!")
            clearInterval(i);
            sb.innerText = "Start";
        }
        }, 1000)
    }
    
    else if (!stop) {
        stop = true;
        sb.innerText = "continue";
// how to change this part to access setInterval variable i?
    }
})
```

Comment: You should be able to simply call `clearInterval(i)` in your `else if`... It isn't **declared** in the `if` statement, only **assigned to**. Have you tried that? What happened instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `clearInterval` within either section of your if-statement, since it is declared outside the scope of both. See here, a working example:

```js
const s = document.querySelector('span');
const b = document.querySelector('button');

let interval = null;
b.onclick = () => {
  // Start the interval
  if (!interval) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      s.innerText = parseInt(s.innerText) - 1;
    }, 1000);
    
    b.innerText = "Pause";
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    
    b.innerText = "Resume";
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="countdown">100</span>
<button>Start</button>
```